# Redis keys not shown while using Cache facade in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I'm using Laravel Cache facade, and the `CACHE_DRIVER=redis`. All data is saved in Redis successfully, but when I use `redis-cli` and run `keys*` there are not keys!

When using the command `flushall in redis-cli` it loads the data again from the database, so that means the keys are already stored in Redis.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Redis has 16 databases indexed 0 - 15. The default database index is `0`, so when you run redis commands without specifying the database index, you're only running commands against database index `0`. However, as of Laravel 5.7, Laravel stores all the cache data in database index `1`.

In order to see the keys in your cache database, you need to query database `1`. You can either use the `-n` switch on the command line to specify the database index, or use the `select` command at the redis prompt to change the active database.

```
redis-cli -n 1 keys "*"
```

or

```
#> redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> select 1
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> keys *
```

Answer (score 3):

### Update

This may have to do with Laravel cache prefixes in the redis block in the database.php config file. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redis#configuration)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66139722/9530790) answer for addtional details.

### Previous Ans.

I had the same issue and I tried the accepted [ans.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56569380/9530790), however different databases was not the issue.

I was able to find the missing key using [scan](https://redis.io/commands/scan), like this `Redis::scan('*')`. Why using `Redis::keys('*')` is not returning the key, is still a mystery.

(To note only key:values created using Python were not returned with `keys`, those created with Laravel were.)

Comment: I saw the same issue. I found out that it does not happen when I set both the `default` and `cache` Redis connection to the same DB number. I'm not sure what Laravel does with the `default` connection but placing the same value for `REDIS_DB` in `database.php` seems to solve it for me.