# Redis CLI not showing recently stored key via Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, in-memory-database

I am trying to cache my results using `redis` in `Laravel` by doing this

```
$result =   Cache::remember('orders_cache', 10, function () use ($orders) {
           return $orders;
        });
        return $result;
```

When I go in my Redis-Cli and do `KEYS *`, I don't see `orders_cache` key there. I have set the `cache_driver` to `redis` in my `.env` and I also ran the command `php artisan config:cache`. I have also installed predis package using composer as well.

My Dev environment is:

- PHP7.4
- Ubuntu 20
- Laravel 6.0
- Redis 5.0.7

Any help on this would be appreciated. 
TIA

Comment: try this commande `redis-cli -n 1 keys "*"` !

Comment: @Maraboc, I see this as an output `(empty list or set)`

Comment: @baig772 if you see `(empty list or set)` its because there is not anything in your databases, this command `redis-cli -n 1 keys "*"` says that show all keys in database with index of 1. that is your case this database is empty

Answer (score 15):

Redis instance supports 16 logical databases and numbered from 0 to 15, by default by runnig `redis-cli` you connect to database `0`. you can take advantage of the Redis INFO command to show databases that contain keys and also another more info like:

```
db0:keys=1,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
db1:keys=2,expires=2,avg_ttl=2462100
```

That in may case, I have 2 database. now you can change the database you’re using with the `select` command after you connect. for example:

```
select 1
```

and it will return `OK` if the switch is successful. now you can see your laravel keys.

Comment: thanks for this comment. i have two question: why redis create other database in the same instance? how could i say it to laravel that use it the 0 database?

Answer (score 6):

run `redis-cli monitor`and check the database number and written key.

Answer (score 6):

In recent versions of Laravel (8.^), it prepends the laravel_database with Redis keys.

E.g: laravel_database_{$YOUR_KEY}.

In order to see what keys are available RUN: `KEYS *`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue in where my key saved via Laravel was being returned, when queried via Laravel, using `Redis::keys('*')`, however a key saved via Python was not. I'm still not sure why (and separate databases as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56569380/9530790) was not the cause).

Interestingly, I was able to see the key, saved via Python, using `Redis::scan('*')` ([docs](https://redis.io/commands/scan)). Even though `scan` returned the key, I am still not able to get it via `Redis::get('key_name')`. I need to do further research as to why this is the case, but this may be useful in finding your missing key.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using the help of @m.nikzad answer, but I didn't know what to do after, so I managed to do it this way:

1. Monitor redis to determine data, database, etc..
2. Connect to the database number.
3. Retrieve the keys you want or all the keys, but be careful to retrieve all keys on a huge database!

So, practical:

1. Monitoring: `redis-cli -h <redis_host> monitor`, where `<redis_host>` is your redis host, you will get something like `SELECT n` in the second line (ig), where `n` is the database number.
2. Now you know the database number, let's connect to it: `redis-cli -h <redis_host> -n <database_number>`, where `<redis_host>` is your redis host & `<database_number>` is your database number that we just got in the previous step. If the redis port is different than the default port, please make sure to include `-p <redis_port>` to the command.
3. Retrieve: either use `KEYS *`, `KEYS <pattern>`, or `GET <key>`, depending on your needs.

Resources:

1. [monitor](https://redis.io/commands/monitor/)
2. [keys](https://redis.io/commands/keys/)
3. [get](https://redis.io/commands/get/)