# Why is Laravel Redis::scan('*') returning an expected key but Redis::keys('*') is not?

Tags: python, laravel, redis

### Problem:

I added a value to redis using Python code, and when I try to query is using Laravel

- `Redis::get('key_name')` it returns `null`.
- `Redis::keys('*')` returns values created using Laravel but not Python
- `Redis::scan('*')` returns all values even those created using Python

### Research:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56569380/9530790, noted this may be a database number issue, however that is not the case. Since I'm using the same database in the Python code as well as the Laravel code, (database `0`)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65278346/9530790, noted the same issue as above.

### Question:

Why is `keys('*')` not returning the key but `scan('*')` is and how can I get the value if `get('key_name')` is returning null?

#### Laravel: `7.30.4`

#### Python: `3.8.3`

#### Redis: `6.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel adds a prefix to all keys created. That prefix is defined in the `redis` config in `database.php`.

`'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),`

I haven't looked at the source code yet but most likely when laravel looks for keys it expects the prefix and appends that to what you passed to `keys` or `get`. So if you passed `keys('key_name')` it'll search for `prefix_key_name` which is why `get` returned `null` and `keys` didn't return my key created via Python as opposed to the one created via Laravel. I guess `scan` works a little differently and returns all keys regardless of its prefix.

If you set the default of your prefix to null (`'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', null`) then your key will be returned.

Using `get` and append the prefix, like this `Redis::get('prefix_key_name')` doesn't work.