# Laravel 8 Sail Redis not assuming the default cache driver

Tags: redis, laravel-facade, laravel-sail

Laravel 8 and the dev environment is Sail - including Redis.
The .env file:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
..
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Using the Redis facade functions, like

```
Redis::set( 'bar', 'The hole of the moon' );
```

using redis-cli is possible to find the value stored in cache

but using

```
Cache::put('bar2', 'baz', 100);
```

or even

```
Cache::store('redis')->put('bar3', 'Awesome', 100);
```

the values cannot be seen using the redis console

Comment: I have the same behavior, did you know the cause ?

Comment: @Mistre83 there is an  explanation

Answer (score 0):

Actually, data is onRedis server...

A nice  explanation here:  [Redis keys not shown while using Cache facade in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566600/redis-keys-not-shown-while-using-cache-facade-in-laravel)

More information here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/cheatsheets/how-to-manage-redis-databases-and-keys