# Redis deleting key when it should set it

Tags: php, laravel, redis

Hey all I have this following code in a Laravel API:

```
if (Hash::check($token_query, $hashed_token))
            {
                Auth::loginUsingId($key->id);
                $getSessionID = session()->getId($key->id);
                $cookie = cookie('session', $getSessionID, 15);
                self::updateIntoDatabase('users', 'identifier', $identifier_query, 'active_session', $getSessionID);
                Cache::put('Session_Token: ' . $getSessionID, true,900);
                return response(["status" => 200, "message" => "Logged in", "loginUsingId:" => Auth::user()], 200)->withCookie($cookie);
            }
```

When using `keys *` after sending this request, nothing appears. However, using `monitor` outputs this:

`1646681598.414829 [0 172.21.0.4:60140] "SELECT" "0"`

`1646681598.415269 [0 172.21.0.4:60140] "DEL" "laravel_database_laravel_cache:9C5AGmh99tVzG9Sc0OTWygfh1pXvFEnCg1Ckr4nB"`

It appears to be selecting the 0th database - which is correct - and then deleting the key?

Here's my config/database.php:

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', 'laravel'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],
```

My config/cache.php:

```
'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'cache',
            'lock_connection' => 'default',
        ],
```

My .env:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=laravel
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to look at here:

1. Your `.env` file has `CACHE_DRIVER` set to `file`, so your caching system is using the filesystem, not redis.
2. If you do change `CACHE_DRIVER` to redis, you do not have the `REDIS_CACHE_DB` env variable set, so the caching system will use redis database 1 for caching. You will need to make sure to select database 1 when attempting to view the keys from the redis cli (see [this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566600/redis-keys-not-shown-while-using-cache-facade-in-laravel/56569380#56569380)).
3. The redis commands that you see happening are the garbage collection for your sessions, which are setup to use redis and database 0. The `StartSession` middleware has a lottery system built in, so that on every request to the application, it will randomly trigger the garbage collection to clean up expired sessions.